# How to store API keys in for a third party web app that accesses an API

Tags: oauth, api-key

Hi all I have been thinking about how there are sites such as [Netlify](https://netlify.com) that get API keys from github once, and then you never have to log in again. How is this done? Can be done with cookies?

The only thing that I could think of for my practice site was storing a key with a users IP address and using this key if they log in on the same address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client-side secrets are typically stored in a browser's localstorage. If it's not strictly a static browser application, store it in your database.